# Spring IS NOT EMPTY query with join fails in many-to-many relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

I am having a repository with the folowing query method

```
@Query("SELECT contents FROM Content contents JOIN contents.mails m WHERE m IS NOT EMPTY AND contents.startDate <= :startDate")
Set<Content> findAllByCreateDateIsBeforeAndMailRecipientsIsNotEmpty(@Param("startDate") Instant startDate);
```

The problem is after I've updated from Spring 2.7.5 to 3.0.1 the following error appear and the Spring Application fails to start.

```
Error interpreting query 
[SELECT contents FROM Content contents JOIN contents.mails m WHERE m IS NOT EMPTY AND contents.startDate <= :startDate]; 
this may indicate a semantic (user query) problem or a bug in the parser 
[SELECT contents FROM Content contents JOIN contents.mails m WHERE m IS NOT EMPTY AND contents.startDate <= :startDate]

class org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.SqmSetJoin 
cannot be cast to class 
org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.SqmPluralValuedSimplePath 
(org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.SqmSetJoin and 
org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.SqmPluralValuedSimplePath 
are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

After I remove the `m IS NOT EMPTY` from the `WHERE STATEMENT` application starts and works as normal, but the query is not as it is ment to be.

NOTE: contens and mails is classical many-to-many relationship deffined in Spring. The DB is Oracle v.19.

What can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You are using IS NOT EMPTY wrong. 'm' is not a collection, it is a path representing a single element from the contents.mails collection. You've done an inner join over that collection, so it must have an entry making 'is not empty' unnecessary. Note though that you are likely joining across a *ToMany relationships, so will get duplicate contents for each 'm' in the mails collection.

Maybe what you wanted was more like `"SELECT contents FROM Content contents where contents.mails IS NOT EMPTY AND contents.startDate <= :startDate"`